# Why is TeamCity build agent marked as "Incompatible"?

Tags: macos, teamcity

I am running TeamCity 8 Server and Build Agent (installed with WebStart) on Mac OSX 10.8

My only build agent is coming up as incompatible with the reason

```
Implicit requirements: 
AppBuildType defined in Build step: Command Line
```

However, my build agent lists:

```
.NET Process Runner: Runner to run .NET processes under specified runtime, framework     version and with/without code coverage
Ant: Runner for Ant build.xml files
Command Line: Simple command execution
Duplicates finder (Java): Runner for gathering IntelliJ IDEA duplicates results
Gradle: Runner for Gradle projects
Inspections (IntelliJ IDEA): Runner for gathering IntelliJ IDEA inspection results
IntelliJ IDEA Project: Runner for IntelliJ IDEA projects
Ipr (obsolete runner): Runner for IntelliJ IDEA project (.ipr) files
Maven: Runner for Maven builds
MSBuild: Runner for MSBuild files
NAnt: Runner for NAnt build files
NUnit: NUnit tests runner
Rake: Runner for executing Rake tasks, Test::Unit and RSpec tests
Visual Studio (sln): Microsoft Visual Studio solution (.sln) runner
Visual Studio 2003: Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003 solution file build runner
Xcode Project: Runner for Xcode projects
```

You can see that `Command Line: Simple command execution` is indeed in my build agent's list of compatible build types - yet it has been marked as NOT compatible.

What else could be causing this to happen? Am I wrong to expect that it should be compatible because the built types match?

Note: I have tried disabling that build step, and it does indeed then become 'compatible'. Renable, and it goes back to 'incompatible' again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**General**

When you see this, double-check your build steps. One of your steps that uses the command line has some invalid arguments.

The easiest way to narrow it down is disable all of the steps (or just the ones with command line) and then start turning them on one at a time, watching to see if it knocks your agent out of compatibility.

**In your case...**

You appear to only have one command line step, so that should be easy. Disable it, and it should show you that you now have compatible agents again. Re-enable it and hack on it until you can get it to work. I've seen problems before with the arguments, the path to files, etc., and you do not get a very helpful error message.

Comment: Thanks Damon - I'll give this a try - I certainly didnt expect this because I wouldn't expect TeamCity to attempt to 'parse' my command line. I figured it would only know there was a problem when it came to execute the script.

Comment: No problem; if you narrow it down but still can't get that step to work, post up the sanitized settings and I'll see if anything jumps out. The one where it got me was something silly, and I got around it by putting the command into a script and calling the script instead of doing it all in the command box.

Comment: Ok - this was the problem. I couldnt get "Command Line" working now matter what I did (including reducing my script to just 'echo hello') - however, I changed the type to "Executable" and after initially having problems with it too - I tracked down that one of the variables used in my parameters wasn't in TeamCity 8's list of options. If anyone from TeamCity is reading this - please update your errors for this scenario, because it's misleading. If you are parsing the script to validate the variables, and one isn't legal, please show this on the web page somewhere!
Thanks Damon

Comment: No problem, glad that helped you track it down. I +1'd your "if anyone from TeamCity is reading this!" :-D

Comment: Had the same issue (tried what you all advised - no effect), then just restarted agent and everything got fixed.